# Azure git ignore

Tags: git, azure, gitignore, ignore

I have a .NET web application that uses some settings from a web.config file. Various instances of this app are installed on azure and each installation has a different connection string in its web.config file that controls the connection with the database. Azure picks the binaries for this app from bitbucket. 
In other words, 10 azure web sites that use the same code, all of them are connected to the same repository in bitbucket and each one of them has a different connection string to a different database.
Each time I create a new release, Azure gets this new release from bitbucket and overwrites web.config of each application. Is there away to instruct Azure to ignore the web.config file from bitbucket when pulling a new Release?

Comment: Are you talking about Azure Web App ? Have you tried Connection Strings and Application Settings in Azure Web App? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/configuration-and-app-settings-of-azure-web-sites/

Comment: This is not a solution, it is just a workarround. It could be used though in the .NET application which is the API but could not be used on a second PHP application (also on Azure) that has connection strings for the API in a config.php file.

Comment: You can use it in PHP also. For example check the code in Pastebin to get connection string in Wordpress: http://pastebin.com/uzNT2RkW

Comment: I have one more question on how to use your suugestions in the .NET App. In my web.config app there is a setting like this <add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Server=SQLserver Name,1433;Database=DBName;User ID=userName;Password=pwd;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> and my code is using the following in order to use this seeting var connectionString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
What changes do I have to make in my code in order to use the Azure App settings?